# "java.net.BindException: Address already in use" despite setting SO_REUSEADDR

Tags: java, nio

I have written this simple NIO server but when running multiple times, one right after another I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at test.Server.start(Server.java:38)
    at test.Server.main(Server.java:93)
```

I have set setReuseAddress(true) before a call to bind. 
I have also tried to call setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true) on ServerSocketChannel but it is still the same.

Can someone point out why it happens?

Here is the code:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Server {

    private ServerSocketChannel ssc;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Selector accept;
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    void start(final CountDownLatch cdl) {
        try {
            this.accept = Selector.open();

            ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            ssc.configureBlocking(false);
            ssc.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true);

            InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9123);
            serverSocket = ssc.socket();
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.bind(isa);
            ssc.register(accept, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (cdl != null) {
                        cdl.countDown();
                    }
                    while (true) {
                        accept.select();
                        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = accept.selectedKeys();
                        Iterator<SelectionKey> i = readyKeys.iterator();
                        while (i.hasNext()) {
                            SelectionKey sk = i.next();
                            if (sk.isValid() && sk.isAcceptable()) {
                                accept(sk);
                            }
                            i.remove();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private void accept(final SelectionKey sk) throws IOException {
                ServerSocketChannel ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) sk.channel();
                SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
                sc.configureBlocking(false);
                sc.register(accept, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                System.out.println("Connection accepted from: "
                        + sc.getRemoteAddress());
            }
        });
    }

    void stop() {
        try {
            executor.shutdown();
            executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Server s = new Server();
        CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
        s.start(cdl);
        cdl.await();
        Client.connect();
        s.stop();
    }
}

class Client {
    static void connect() {
        try {
            new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9123);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run several servers simultaneously (i.e. "started one after another and then run together"), or do you start another server right after the first one exits? SO_REUSEADDR doesn't help in the first situation.

Comment: You don't need to call it twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have two different invocations of your code listening on the same adapter and port number.  This is the way the TCP/IP stack works.  If you did, how would the stack know which process gets the connection?  `SO_REUSEADDR` has nothing to do with this.

From [What exactly does SO_REUSEADDR do?](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml)

> This socket option tells the kernel that even if this port is busy
>   (in   the TIME_WAIT state), go ahead and reuse it anyway.  If it is
>   busy,   but with another state, you will still get an address already
>   in use   error.  It is useful if your server has been shut down, and
>   then   restarted right away while sockets are still active on its
>   port.  You   should be aware that if any unexpected data comes in, it
>   may confuse   your server, but while this is possible, it is not
>   likely.

In other words, if you've closed the socket but it's still waiting for the connection to quiesce (receive the FIN/ACK or timeout) you can immediately grab it again.  You can never have two processes connected to the same endpoint at the same time.